# How to know all possible hierarchies in Cadence Innovus for a given design?

Tags: cadence

I want to know all the possible hierarchies in the design like dl1, dl1/dl2, dl1/dl2/dl3, etc. where dl1, dl2, and dl3 indicate the depths in the design. Is there any command for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple command db.fplan.group.name which will give all the different groups to which it might belong. That's what I have found out untill now. I'm not exactly sure if it is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an answer or should be part of the question. It doesn't currently seem to be a definitive answer, more like speculation on your part..?